# Alfresco : Access to properties file from java class

Tags: java, internationalization, alfresco, ecm

I want to know how to access to a properties file that is under share from a `java class (under alfresco)` which will be exported later as a `.jar` file under `alfresco/lib`.

Answer (score 1):

As reported in [this](https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/end-user-discussions/alfresco-share/access-properties-file-under-shared-folder-java-class) Alfresco forum post you should register a Spring bean in your context exploiting the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`, setting the proper location of you properties file will be found.

```
<bean id="custom-properties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders">
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:alfresco/extension/custom.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

From now on every time you define a bean you can use placeholders taken from the property file, which has a common `key=value` format.